# C# Variable To JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
<index>
<div>

string selectedvalue="";

// Coding Part

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function onchangeFT(e)
 {
     '@selectedvalue'= e.value; //e.value come form combobox and it is should be assigned to "selectedvalue"
        alert('@selectedvalue');
 }

</script>
```

Comment: Is this a real question? looks like trolling around.

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do? The title is vague and i see no question in your post...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var selectedvalue="";

    function onchangeFT(e)
     {
         selectedvalue = e.value; //e.value come form combobox and it is should be assigned to 
            alert(selectedvalue);
     }

</script>
```

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong, but it's definitely not answering the question title: _"C# Variable To JavaScript"_. Yes, I blame the OP for his low quality "question".

Comment: @gdoron - I think question title is wrong - look at the code comment.

Comment: I think the OP is wrong for posting this low quality question. What the heck is he trying to do? I believe he wants to change something in the server via javascript. He obviously mixing client and server side